# How to solve partial differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

How to solve in *Mathematica* this partial differential equation:
$0.5\frac{\partial t(x,y)}{\partial x}+1.5\frac{\partial t(x,y)}{\partial y}+t(x,y)=y\cdot \sqrt{1+x^{3}}$ with condition $t(1,y)=y+2$?

I tried this:

```
DSolve[{0.5*D[t[x,y], x] + 1.5*D[t[x,y], y] + t[x,y] == y*Sqrt[1 + x^3]}, 
  t[1, y] == y + 2, t[x,y], {x,y}]
```

but after compilation I saw this message

> DSolve::dsvar: "{a,b} cannot be used as a variable."

Comment: `DSolve[{0.5*D[t[x, y], x] + 1.5*D[t[x, y], y] + t[x, y] == y*Sqrt[1 + x^3], t[1, y] == y + 2}, t[x, y], {x, y}]`?

Comment: There is no `a` or `b` in your code, so presumably you have some leftover variable definitions. Try clearing them.

Comment: You need to include the boundary condition `t[1, y] == y + 2` inside the list of equations, not give it as a second argument. (This is what @Karsten7 showed but I thought it worth pointing out the change explicitly)

Comment: Still I didn't receive solution. Now in output I've got the same thing as in input DSolve[{0.5*D[t[x, y], x] + 1.5*D[t[x, y], y] + t[x, y] == 
   y*Sqrt[1 + x^3], t[1, y] == y + 2}, t[x, y], {x, y}]

Comment: @stitch. That indicates that *Mathematica* can't solve the differential equation analytically in the form that you've written it (and it's possible that there is no analytic solution). This means that you'll likely have to solve it numerically by using `NDSolve`.

Answer (score 1):

In 13.2 on Windows 10

```
DSolve[{1/2*D[t[x, y], x] + 3/2*D[t[x, y], y] + t[x, y] == 
y*Sqrt[1 + x^3], t[1, y] == y + 2}, t[x, y], {x, y}]
```

> `{{t[x, y] -> -E^(-2 x) (-5 E^2 + 3 E^2 x - E^2 y +  Inactive[Integrate][ 2 E^(2 K[1]) (-3 x + y + 3 K[1]) Sqrt[1 + K[1]^3], {K[1], 1, 1}] - Inactive[Integrate][ 2 E^(2 K[1]) (-3 x + y + 3 K[1]) Sqrt[1 + K[1]^3], {K[1], 1, x}])}}`